# Pentaho dynamic merge key fields

Tags: dynamic, merge, key, pentaho

I am trying to perform a merge in Kettle Pentaho. One table will be merged with exactly the same table on another database. The table name to be merged will be passed as an argument so I will have a config table in my db that will contain the column(s) on which the 2 instances of the table have to be joined on.

My question is, can I do a merge with dynamic key fields? I could have a separate step/transformation that selects the names of the columns to be used as keys from the config table.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the `ETL Metadata injection` step?

Comment: I don't think `ETL Metadata injection` will solve this.

Comment: I am looking into that now but Merge Join is not one of the steps mentioned in the table of steps that support Metadata Injection

Answer (score 0):

Better to do the merge with static fields, but use separate steps to populate those fields dynamically with the values you want to merge by.  Remember to sort after you populate the fields!